# Change signal color based on value fetch from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to change the color of the signal point based on value fetch from API in React, for example: if value < 50, color is green, else 50 < value < 100, color is yellow, else value > 100 color is red.

StatusCard.jsx

```
StatusCard.propTypes = {
    values: PropTypes.array,
};

StatusCard.defaultProps = {
    values: [],
}
function StatusCard(props) {
    const { values } = props;
    const signal ="dot-good"
    return (
        <div>
            {values.map(value => (
                <div className='status-card '>
                    <div className="status-card__info">
                    
                        <h4><i className={props.icon}></i> {props.area}</h4>
                        <h5>Air Quality: {value.field3} AQI <span className={signal}></span></h5>
                        <br />
                        <h5>Noise Level: {value.field4} dB <span className={signal}></span></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default StatusCard
```

Can I change the className based on value fetch from API

statusCard.css

```
.dot-good {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    background-color: lime;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dot-moderate {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dot-unhealthy {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What should happen if the `value` is exactly 50, or 100?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
const signal = value.field3 < 50 ? "dot-unhealthy" : value.field3 < 100 && value.field3 > 50 ? "dot-moderate" : "dot-good"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `value.field3 < 100 && value.field3 > 50` for moderate?